# Object is nil segue in swift

Tags: swift, segue

I'm trying to pass an object from one view controller to another, but the receiver receives **nil** and throws an error saying:
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "sPropSegue" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let prop = modelProperty.props[indexPath.row]
                
                let dVeiwController = segue.destination as? PDViewController
                
                detailVeiwController?.property = prop
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

code in the UIViewController

```
var property: Property!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        propImage.image = UIImage(named: property.imageName)
        priceLable.text = property.price
        addressTextView.text = property.address        //propImage.image = UIImage()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

please help me solving this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `detailVeiwController?.property = prop` called? How do you trigger the "segue"? By code? By connecting in the Storyboard from the cell to the next view controller? If yes, remove it, and do it from the viewcontroller to the next one, and in didSelectRow, call `performSegue()`

Comment: I triggered using the connecting the cell through the storyboard

Comment: Are you sure the destination is a PDViewcontroller?  Have you the view controller's properties on the storyboard to the correct class, as if not this would cause a nil value from the conditional chaining?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure segue is established from the Source vc ( not the table cell ) to the destination vc for `override func prepare(for segue` to be called

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier:"sPropSegue",sender:nil)
}
```

Comment: I tried establishing the segue from VC but the cell click even is not get fired.

Comment: Set table delegate and try above

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding you are not getting property object in your PDViewController.

So try to debug it. Make sure that prop is not nil.

Try executing the same code after commenting viewDidLoad() code.

Also make sure you have `self.table.delegate = self` in the controller where you are trying to perform segue.

Comment: This would be better as a comment than an answer as it is advice on how to solve the problem rather than a solution to the problem.